# Mapping articles from folder into a list

Tags: python, string, list, function

I have a folder with few articles and I would like to map text of each article into a common list in order to use the list for the tf-idf transformation. For example:

folder = [article1, article2, article3]

into list

list = ['text_of_article1', 'text_of_article2', 'text_of_article3']

```
def multiple_file(arg):     #arg is path to the folder with multiple files
    '''Function opens multiple files in a folder and maps each of them to a list
    as a string'''
    import glob, sys, errno
    path = arg
    files = glob.glob(path)
    list = []               #list where file string would be appended
    for item in files:    
        try:
            with open(item) as f: # No need to specify 'r': this is the default.
                list.append(f.read())
        except IOError as exc:
            if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR: # Do not fail if a directory is found, just ignore it.
                raise # Propagate other kinds of IOError.
    return list
```

When I set the path to the folder with my articles I get an empty list. However, when I set it directly to one article, then that article appears in the list. How could I get all of them mapped into my list. :S

This is the code, not sure if this is what you had in mind:

```
def multiple_files(arg):     #arg is path to the folder with multiple files
    '''Function opens multiple files in a folder and maps each of them to a list
    as a string'''
    import glob, sys, errno, os
    path = arg
    files = os.listdir(path)
    list = []               #list where file string would be appended
    for item in files:    
        try:
            with open(item) as f: # No need to specify 'r': this is the default.
                list.append(f.read())
        except IOError as exc:
            if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR: # Do not fail if a directory is found, just ignore it.
                raise # Propagate other kinds of IOError.
    return list
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-13e1457699ff>", line 1, in <module>
    x = multiple_files(path)

  File "<ipython-input-5-6a8fab5c295f>", line 10, in multiple_files
    with open(item) as f: # No need to specify 'r': this is the default.

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'u02.txt'
```

Article No. 2 is actually the first one in the newly created list.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `path == "/home/docs/guzdeh"`. If you just say `glob.glob(path)` you only get `[path]` because nothing else matches the pattern. You want `glob.glob(path + "/*")` to get everything in that directory, or `glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")` for all the `txt` files.

Alternatively you could use `import os; os.listdir(path)`, which I think makes more sense.

UPDATE:

Regarding the new code, the problem is that `os.listdir` only returns the path relative to the directory listed. Therefore you need to combine the two for python to know where you're talking about. Add:

```
item = os.path.join(path, item)
```

before trying to `open(item)`. You might also want to name your variables better.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried them all out and all of them shuffle my articles, with glob approaches even duplicating some of the articles. I do not understand, I need articles to be order like they are in my folder. Moreover, os.listdir(path) approach also reported an error that second article is not present but then it maps it into my list. Hm... :S

Comment: Let's stick to os.listdir. Use that, edit your question to show the latest code, and include all the details about these errors and the results.

Comment: Hey, do you know what could be the problem? :)

Comment: @guzdeh Hi, sorry, didn't know you'd edited. Updated my answer.